selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
I tried use different setup for selenium from stackoverflow and github but, im also get this error:
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\utils\tabs_setup.py", line 19, in open_windows
        driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{url}');")
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 407, in execute_script
        return self.execute(command, {"script": script, "args": converted_args})["value"]
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 300.000
    (Session info: chrome=124.0.6367.208)
    Stacktrace:
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D6DF1502+60802]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6D6AC02]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C27CE4]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C10FE1]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C10D42]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C0EBE4]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C0F3FF]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C1E0F8]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C357CF]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C3B38A]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C0FB85]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C3550E]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6CBA0FF]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C9A923]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C68FEC]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6C69C21]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D70F411D+3217821]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D71360B7+3488055]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D712F03F+3459263]
            GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7D6EAB846+823494]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6D75F9F]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6D70EC4]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6D71052]
            (No symbol) [0x00007FF7D6D618A4]
            BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFB9C7184D4+20]
            RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFB9CE21791+33]

As I understand it, correct me if I'm wrong, the computer is disconnecting from the selenium drivers or can't wait for the command to open the link URL
seleniumbase webdriver:
    driver = Driver(
        uc=True,
        disable_gpu=True,
        disable_csp=True,
        ad_block_on=True,
        uc_subprocess=True,
        page_load_strategy='eager',
        extension_dir='utils/nopecha',
        locale_code='en_us',
    )     

Function where i get error:
    def open_windows(driver, option):
        url_list = _get_url(option)
        for url in url_list:
            driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{url}');")
            sleep(2)

